# Continuously forward and reverse Transition?

Tags: java, android, transition, infinite-loop, freeze

I am trying to develop an activity for emergency situations. I want that background must change according to a transition xml continuously. Transition is between colors black and red. I implemented a counter and when it ends I started it again to use it infinitely.

**Here is my code :**

```
package com.example.transitionbetweencolors;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    RelativeLayout relative_layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        relative_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout);
        relative_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.transition_colors);
        final TransitionDrawable drawable = (TransitionDrawable) relative_layout.getBackground();

          CountDownTimer x = new CountDownTimer(1000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            drawable.startTransition(1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
        //    showNotification();
            drawable.reverseTransition(1000);
            start();// here, when your CountDownTimer has finished , we start it again :)
        }
    };
    x.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I couldn't get what I want from my code. It does forward transition, and then it does reverse transition. It does this 3 or 4 time and at that time something happens, continuity break downs. It starts to cycle again in the same manner.

Any suggestions or any other ideas would be welcome.

Comment: "something happens" , is might be `StackoverflowException`

Comment: @Kedarnath Can you explain StackoverflowException further? And how can I understand it is exactly that exception? There is no any exception in log.

Comment: Basically what you did is known as Recursion , meaning a method calling it self again & again. Each time you are calling it, it creates occupies a memory block for the method and when that memory block get's full, your code stop working, that stage is known as `StackOverflowException`